# JDBC escape processing and HSQLDB regular expression syntax

Tags: hsqldb

What's wrong with this HSQLDB syntax:

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(Title, '([0-9]{4})$')
```

The regular expression is intended to remove 4 digits in parentheses at the end of a string. Thanks for taking a look.

I tried various escaping with no success. Apparently the curly braces are being intercepted by JDBC as an escape sequence of its own.

Comment: I clearly have a fundamental misunderstanding of how regular expressions are parsed through JDBC and HSQLDB. Any help would be heartily appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn JDBC escape processing off.

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setEscapedProcessing(false);
statement.executeQuery("select REGEXP_REPLACE(Title, '([0-9]{4})$') from mytable");
```

The `statement.setEscapedProcessing(false)` has no effect on a `PreparedStatement`.